# remove everything in sidebar but one menu

Tags: magento

I am integrating blog(wordpress) into our magento site. I am at the point to update handler in the blog.xml file. I want to display in sidebar only the blog menu but not other menus that are by default in the right sidebar. I know i can remove the right sidebar all together but then there is not sidebar to attach my blog menu.

How to do this - add single menu and remove rest of the menues in the sidebar?

Thank you,

Margots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy,

you can use `unsetChild` to remove content from any bar you like, and `append` to add
any block you want.

See here how to use:

[Magento Layout Files Reference](http://magsvento.se/magento-references/magento-layout-files-reference)

Or remove the complete sidebar and set your block you want to show in your sidebar with `as="right"`
in your layout update xml.

Z

Comment: Thank you. I was able to do it one way but not quite another way.

In the following is one way that worked: 
   <remove name="right" />
   <reference name="root">
     <block type="blog2/blog" name="sideBlog" as="right" template="blog2/side.phtml"/>
   </reference>

Comment: Here is the second way that need your help please
<br>

   <reference name="right">
      <action method="unsetChildren"></action>
      <action method="append"><block>blog.menue</block></action>
</reference>


How do i create the blog.menu block in the layout file? I know how to do it in code, but i want to keep all structural work in layout file.

Comment: How do you format these posts?...sorry
Thanks Again for helping to learn

Comment: Hy,

`unsetChild` is the correct value - NOT `unsetChildren`; if you want to unset more than one block, you have to unset every block on its own

Comment: Zungerl, How will you know the names of all blocks in the sidebar? By unsetChildren you can remove all and then add blocks you need.